# Unable to access file from network drive

Tags: java, weblogic

I am creating a virtual directory mapping in WebLogic by passing the network location and it doesn't seem to be working.

```xml
<wls:virtual-directory-mapping>
    <wls:local-path>\\iso19prod\NAPDC_AUS_Images\</wls:local-path>
    <wls:url-pattern>Approved/*</wls:url-pattern>
</wls:virtual-directory-mapping>
```

Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 0):

```
<wls:virtual-directory-mapping>
    <wls:local-path>//iso19prod/NAPDC_AUS_Images/</wls:local-path>
    <wls:url-pattern>Approved/*</wls:url-pattern>
</wls:virtual-directory-mapping>
```

This solved my problem